# Saving manim video as infinite loop GIF

Tags: python, manim

I already figured out how to save manim script as GIF using [that video](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwipn6rZ_svqAhUyD2MBHRuaBMIQwqsBMAB6BAgKEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DjuFfUwJUTtI&usg=AOvVaw1bxqUR_5K0s8lyl8eyhshv).

Although I would like to use it as loop animation and it seems that the default exporting using manim library plays it once.

Is it possible to change the configurations to make it infinitly looping.

Thanks

Comment: The loop is already activated in that tutorial.

Comment: You're right! sorry I had many wait commands at the end of my script and that made me think it ends up that way.